# Blue J Word Collider Part 2

Tags: java, bluej

Earlier i asked a question specifically for the animate method in my word collider program. The purpose of this program is that when two words collide the words will explode and each individual character will be scattered randomly on the screen. Below is the code for my program;

```
/**
 * Write a description of class WordCollider here.
 * 
 * @author 
 * @version 
 */

public class WordCollider
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private Text word1;
    private Text word2;
    // the characters contained in word1
    private Text[] charWord1;
    // the characters contained in word2
    private Text[] charWord2;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class WordCollider
     */
    public WordCollider(String w1, String w2)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        word1 = new Text(w1);
        word1.randomizePosition();
        word1.changeColor("green");
        word1.changeSize(48);
        word1.makeVisible();
        word2 = new Text(w2);
        word2.randomizePosition();
        word2.changeColor("orange");
        word2.changeSize(48);
        word2.makeVisible();
        charWord1 = new Text[w1.length()];
        charWord2 = new Text[w2.length()];
        fillChars(charWord1, w1);
        fillChars(charWord2, w2);
    }

    private void fillChars(Text[] a, String w) {
        char[] cs = w.toCharArray();
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = new Text(""+cs[i]);
            a[i].changeSize(48);
            a[i].changeColor("red");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Randomize the position of the two words repeatedly and stop
     * when the bounding box of the two words overlaps.
     */
    public void animate()
    {
        while(checkOverlap() == false){
            word1.randomizePosition();
            word2.randomizePosition();
        }

        while(checkOverlap() == true){ 
            word1.makeInvisible();
            word2.makeInvisible();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < charWord1.length; i++){
            word1.makeVisible();
            word1.randomizePosition();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < charWord2.length; i++){
            word2.makeVisible();
            word2.randomizePosition();
        }
    }

    /**
     * erase the words and any other characters on the display
     */
    public void clearDisplay() {
        word1.makeInvisible();
        word2.makeInvisible();
    }

    /**
     * check if the bounding box of the two words overlaps.
     * @return true when the words overlap and false otherwise.
     */
    private Boolean checkOverlap() {

        if (word2.getXPosition() < word1.getXPosition() + word1.getTextWidth()){
            return true;
        }

        if (word1.getXPosition() > word2.getXPosition() + word2.getTextWidth()){
            return true;
        }

        if (word2.getYPosition() < word1.getYPosition() - word1.getTextHeight()){
            return true;
        }

        if (word1.getYPosition() > word2.getYPosition() - word2.getTextHeight()){
            return true;
        }

        if (word2.getXPosition() < word1.getXPosition() + word1.getTextWidth() && word1.getXPosition() > word2.getXPosition() + word2.getTextWidth()){
            return true;
        }

        if (word2.getYPosition() < word1.getYPosition() - word1.getTextHeight() && word1.getYPosition() > word2.getYPosition() - word2.getTextHeight()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The purpose of the animate method is if checkOverlap is false the word will be randomized on the screen whereas if checkOverlap is true then i want to make the word invisible and scatter the letters on the screen

The purpose of the clear display method is just to make the words invisible on screen.

The purpose of the checkOverlap method is to check whether or not the two words overlap, if they do overlap then the return statement will be true and if they don't overlap then it will return false

How can i go round fixing this so my program works?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking.  Is there a bug that needs to be fixed?  Or do you need help writing new code?

Comment: I need some help writing the code, this is what i've come up with so far so any help would be appreciated

Comment: OK... so where exactly are you stuck?  Please be as specific as possible to avoid making this look like a "please do my homework for me" question.

Comment: Im having a problem specifically with the animate method. Depending on whether the condition is met i want the words to explode and all the letters scattered on screen. Im not sure how to write the code for this

Comment: So if you made each letter a "word" and scattered them around the screen, would that work?

Comment: I assume it would work but im not sure how to write the code for it since i initially have 2 variables for each word would it mean i have to make new variables? Or would the ones i specified in the program code be enough?

Comment: That or an array.  That would work too.

Comment: Im not sure how i'd write the code to this because i haven't dealt with arrays before, i started programming a couple months ago and im relatively new to this. Could you show some code of how it would look if possible?

Comment: @BeginnerBlueJ Reading your two questions (one posted a few hours ago, and this one) it doesn't seem like there's any difference in the question. Why post both?

Comment: @David Ben Knoble: The first part was just regarding the animate method however im unsure whether or not the changes required in the animate method also require changes elsewhere. I need help writing the code

Comment: Right but neither post asks a direct specific question about what isnt working and what you expect it to do.

Comment: I have specified what i want the program to do. When the two words which i have entered as parameters overlap i want the words to explode and the letters forming each of the words will be scattered over the screen.

Comment: In regards to what is problematic in my program it's the animate method. Within the animate method if the checkOverlap method is true i want the words to explode with letters scattered over the screen